# Google isn't surfacing Events rich snippets in SERP when JSON-LD Structured Data is valid

Tags: google-search-console, rich-snippets, structured-data, google-rich-snippets-tool, json-ld

Google confirms our site has thousands of valid MusicEvent structured data objects presented using JSON-LD, as indicated in the Structured Data section of Webmaster Tools. However, rich snippets for the events do not show up in any search result pages. The Rich Cards tab in Webmaster Tools says:

> We did not find any structured data for rich cards on your website.

The structured data is valid with no errors in the Structured Data Testing Tool. We do generate some warnings occasionally for missing endDate and price fields. Comparing our code to a survey of other sites whose rich snippets do appear, we are not doing anything unique in terms of our markup.

The data has been there for months, in fact over the months we've tried also using Microdata format. The Structured Data section indicates that many pages were crawled this week.

Besides SDTT validation, what else can I check to troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: I work in events and ticketing on SEO - would you be able to give an example of the markup you're trying and a competitor where it's working? It's likely that this is an issue only Google can answer but more information could shed some light.

Comment: It is possible that Google disabled rich snippets for your site due to them looking like web spam.   See: http://webmeup.com/blog/spammy-structured-markup.html

Answer (score 2):

had to struggle with similar issue - got repaired it, after i rearranged my structured markup so, that `Event` became a highest entity of the page - highest in terms of nesting.

But other quality issues, specially a kind of Stephen Ostermiller mentioned, should be controlled and, if any, eliminated at first.

Answer (score 1):

Content on the web page must match the Structured data you are inserting to the page. Description, dates (Day, Month, Year.) If it does not match, Google will deem this inconsistent with the structured data. Make sure your event listing page or calendar is being indexed as well.